# Wordpress: get posts in specific categories

Tags: wordpress

I want list posts from given categories which belong to certain post ids.

Example: Posts from categoryA or categoryB which has the id 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: How can i search using both categories and post ids

Answer (score 2):

Using `get_posts` with the `post__in` and `cat` will likely meet your needs.:

```
// Create your query argument array
$args = array(
        'cat'   => '1,2', // Where 1 and 2 are the category ids of Category A and Category B that you want posts containing either of.
        'post__in' => array (1,2,3,4,5) // Where 1-5 are post ids
    );

// Retrieve posts
$post_list = get_posts( $args );
```

`$post_list` will be an array of posts retrieved based on the query parameters passed to `get_posts`.

You can get more info on `get_posts` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and more info on valid query parameters [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters).

Comment: but you cant use both categories and post ids at the same time with get_posts

Comment: I added some code that shows how to convert category slugs or names to ids.

Comment: Also, you really should rewrite the question to more clearly state what your actual issue is.

Comment: I have a list of post ids (1,2,5,6,7). I want to search the posts belong to catA or catB within those 5 posts

Comment: Oh...that's not at all what it sounded like you wanted from your original post.

Comment: My current answer should provide you with what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) with the category and include arguments.

Comment: but you cant use both categories and post ids at the same time with get_posts

Comment: Can u explain how to search both in a single query